# Защита фонового активити от остановки

Tags: android, java

Есть приложение с активити, которое запускается при каждом запуске системы и висит в системе. Делаю так:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.ad.cd"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Проблема в том, что при нехватки ОЗУ система хлопает апу. Есть выход создать постоянное уведомление (делал без иконки), но юзеров это бесит + якобы траты лишних 5МБ.
Есть ли другие выходы?

Защита root (видел апы, если хлопнуть выдаёт "Приложению * предоставлен ROOT" и оно снова в строю), невидимое уведомление (minsdk=9, хотя и 14 сойдёт), другие методы?
Буду благодарен за совет!

Comment: Может быть стоит переписать функционал на Service?

Comment: Зачем вы разводите говнокод? И еще хотите, что бы кто-то вместо вас в нем поковырялся? Для этого существуют сервисы, ни как не Активити. Сделайте по человечески, и ни кто не вздумает убивать вашу задачу при нехватке памяти.

Comment: metalurgus, Ваш комментарий ну ОЧЕНЬ уместен!

Comment: @MoNTE48 возможно комментарий  @metalurgus Вам кажется излишне резким, но он действительно уместен, он не содержит хамства, только объективную критику, объективно если в более мягкой форме чем сказал это @metalurgus, то Ваш код не оптимален и решает задачу не теми методами, которыми стоило бы. Но его комментарий намного лучше передает суть, Вам действительно стоит использовать Service.

Comment: @MoNTE48 не хотел ни кого обижать, это скорее такая себе пародия на злого программиста...

Comment: Код не совсем мой. Open Sourse переписываю.
Да, там и был сервис. Затупил!
Выходит держать в ОЗУ - только уведомлением можно? А кастомное уведомление transparent/0px реально?

Comment: @MoNTE48 а я че-то не врубаюсь - где здесь активити? Вижу пока только ресивер или я чего-то не догоняю?

Comment: @Barmaley, лично мне кажется, что при событии BOOT_COMPLETED ресивер запускает активити.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, хорошим выходом из вашей ситуации будет простая проверка( скажем, каждую минуту ).
Проверку, не зависимую от UI можно организовать с помощью системного сервиса [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Он позволяет выполнять различные события( запускать активности, посылать намерения ), заданные на **конкретное** время( и с конкретным интервалом ).
В общем, почитайте - уверен, это поможет вам.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых переделать на сервис, а во вторых запускать его через **startForeground**()
Пример тут: [Android development. Бессмертный сервис](http://development-for-android.blogspot.ru/2012/01/blog-post_3068.html)

Так он станет не убиваемым

Comment: Так это тоже оповещение. А иначе никак?

Comment: Читай примечание в статье внизу ))) красным цветом
P.S. 1. Все это работает начиная с версии 2.0.
        2. Метод startForeground обязательно требует оповещение (т.е. null передать не получиться) Сделано это для того, чтобы пользователь всегда знал, что сервис работает. Иными словами сервис, который будет инкогнито, сделать не получиться. :)